# ANSI-C pow function and type casting

Tags: c, math, casting, ansi-c

This simple program below does not build for some reason. It says "undefined reference to pow" but the math module is included and I'm building it with -lm flag. It builds if I use the pow like pow(2.0, 4.0), so I suspect there is something wrong with my type casting.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      printf("2 to the power of %d = %f\n", i, pow(2.0, (double)i));
   }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the bulid log:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project hello ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/hello.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g -pedantic -Wall -c -lm -ansi -MMD -MP -MF"src/hello.d" -MT"src/hello.d" -o "src/hello.o" "../src/hello.c"
Finished building: ../src/hello.c

Building target: hello
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc  -o "hello"  ./src/hello.o   
./src/hello.o: In function `main':
/home/my/workspace/hello/Debug/../src/hello.c:19: undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've told it to use the math library in the wrong place -- you're specifying the math library when you compile (where it won't help) but leaving it out when you link (where it's actually needed). You need to specify it when you link:

```
gcc -o "hello" ./src/hello.o -lm
```

Comment: What Jerry's saying is that you're not passing it in the linking phase.  See the line just after `Invoking: GCC C Linker`.  Maybe can you post your Makefile?